# how to get user email after access token generate in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have generated an access token and refresh token successfully with PHP Oauth 2.0 with the following code, I want to store refresh token and user email in my database . I have refresh token but not sure how to get user email.

```
<?php 
require  '../vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret_234rcontent.com.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
 '/google_calendar2/oauth2callback.php');
 // offline access will give you both an access and refresh token so that
 // your app can refresh the access token without user interaction.
 $client->setAccessType('offline');
 // Using "consent" ensures that your application always receives a refresh token.
// If you are not using offline access, you can omit this.
$client->setPrompt('consent');
$client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

Redirect uri code

```
<?php
require  'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret_2344056t4.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
'/google_calendar2/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$credentials=$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
// $refresh_token = $credentials['refresh_token'];
print_r($credentials);
```

resposne
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnb8Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the Google APK, but with a normal API request you can do:

`GET`: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token={access_token}`

Reponse:

```
{
  "sub": "116289810291163096502",
  "name": "John Smith",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Smith",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh10GhaIqIxRM0PbSwNMA7hFltGP7P1CzvUbCtcpyDHqg=s96-c",
  "email": "john.smith@example.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "locale": "en",
  "hd": "example.com"
}
```